# common lisp format: call function with slash in name using ~/ directive

Tags: io, format, common-lisp

The format function in common lisp has a `~/name/` directive which allows you to call an arbitrary function to format a value. However, according to the docs, the name cannot have a / in it. However, #/ is a valid character in a symbol, and therefore a function name. So, is there any way to escape a #/ in a function name passed to the ~//  directive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really.

But you could write a function with a legal name, which calls the function, which then needs to be passed with the argument. Similar to this example:

```
(defun foo (&rest args)
  (apply (first (second args))
         (first args)
         (second (second args))
         (cddr args)))

CL-USER 52 > (defun ba/r (&rest args) (print args))
BA/R

CL-USER 53 > (format t "~/foo/" '(ba/r (1 2)))

(#<LW-XP::XP-STRUCTURE 41C00D8B1B> (1 2) NIL NIL) 
NIL
```

Answer (score 1):

> #### [22.3.5.4 Tilde Slash: Call Function](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/22_ced.htm)
>
> ```
> ~/name/
> ```
>
> User defined functions can be called from within a format string by
>   using the directive ~/name/. The colon modifier, the at-sign modifier,
>   and arbitrarily many parameters can be specified with the ~/name/
>   directive. name can be any arbitrary string that does not contain a
>   "/". All of the characters in name are treated as if they were upper
>   case. If name contains a single colon (:) or double colon (::), then
>   everything up to but not including the first ":" or "::" is taken to
>   be a string that names a package. Everything after the first ":" or
>   "::" (if any) is taken to be a string that names a symbol. The
>   function corresponding to a ~/name/ directive is obtained by looking
>   up the symbol that has the indicated name in the indicated package. If
>   name does not contain a ":" or "::", then the whole name string is
>   looked up in the COMMON-LISP-USER package.

There are lots of symbols that you won't be able to call using the tilde-slash directive;  symbols containing a `#\/` are just one kind.   Others are those with colons in their names, or that have lower case letters.